# I need to parse json result in windows phone app c#

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-phone-8, json.net

Im new in developing windows phone app --> i have problem so i have tried all the possible solutions but with no vain:-
the application tried to take result from webservice the result come back like this:-

{"d":"{\"sessionid\":null,\"VersionInfo\":{\"Rel\":0,\"Ver\":0,\"Patch\":0,\"ForceUpdate\":0,\"UpdateType\":0,\"Globals\":{\"MultiSessionsAllowed\":true,\"CommCalcType\":1,\"PriceChangedTimer\":20,\"ValidLotsLocation\":2,\"CustumizeTradeMsg\":true,\"FirstWhiteLabeledOffice\":null,\"DealerTreePriv\":0,\"ClientConnectTimer\":200,\"ClientTimeoutTimer\":500,\"DefaultLots\":0.01,\"WebSecurityID\":\"agagag\",\"ServerGMT\":3}},\"SystemLockInfo\":{\"MinutesRemaining\":0,\"HoursRemaining\":0,\"DaysRemaining\":0,\"Maintanance\":0,\"WillBeLocked\":1},\"FirstWhiteLabel\":\"HS Dev\",\"WLID\":\"3\",\"CheckWhiteLabel\":true,\"Password\":\"1234\",\"Username\":\"obeidat\",\"LastTickTime\":\"\/Date(1396613678728)\/\",\"SelectedAccount\":12345791,\"Name\":0,\"CompanyName\":\"HS Dev\",\"UserId\":579,\"DemoClient\":\"0\",\"FName\":\"obeidat\",\"SName\":null,\"TName\":null,\"LName\":null,\"Sms\":null,\"isReadOnly\":\"0\",\"SchSms\":\"0\",\"AlertSms\":\"0\",\"Temp\":null,\"GMTOffset\":\"5\",\"SvrGMT\":\"3\",\"ClientType\":null,\"EnableNews\":\"0\",\"PublicSlideNews\":\"\",\"PrivateSlideNews\":\"Thanks for using our platform##We will inform you here with any private news\",\"DealerTreePriv\":1}"}

so i have tried to parse it but it give me errors after that i have tried locally  removed the {"d":" and \"LastTickTime\":\"\/Date(1396613678728)\/\" from the string with no connection to webservice and its working fine i use this code :-

```
   // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    //Json classes
    public class OuterRootObject
    {
        public string d { get; set; }
    }

    public class Globals
    {
        public bool MultiSessionsAllowed { get; set; }
        public int CommCalcType { get; set; }
        public int PriceChangedTimer { get; set; }
        public int ValidLotsLocation { get; set; }
        public bool CustumizeTradeMsg { get; set; }
        public object FirstWhiteLabeledOffice { get; set; }
        public int DealerTreePriv { get; set; }
        public int ClientConnectTimer { get; set; }
        public int ClientTimeoutTimer { get; set; }
        public double DefaultLots { get; set; }
        public string WebSecurityID { get; set; }
        public int ServerGMT { get; set; }
    }

    public class VersionInfo
    {
        public int Rel { get; set; }
        public int Ver { get; set; }
        public int Patch { get; set; }
        public int ForceUpdate { get; set; }
        public int UpdateType { get; set; }
        public Globals Globals { get; set; }
    }

    public class SystemLockInfo
    {
        public int MinutesRemaining { get; set; }
        public int HoursRemaining { get; set; }
        public int DaysRemaining { get; set; }
        public int Maintanance { get; set; }
        public int WillBeLocked { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string sessionid { get; set; }
        public VersionInfo VersionInfo { get; set; }
        public SystemLockInfo SystemLockInfo { get; set; }
        public string FirstWhiteLabel { get; set; }
        public string WLID { get; set; }
        public bool CheckWhiteLabel { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastTickTime { get; set; }
        public int SelectedAccount { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public object ServicePath { get; set; }
        public string GWSessionID { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public string SessionDateStart { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string DemoClient { get; set; }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string SName { get; set; }
        public string TName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public object Sms { get; set; }
        public string isReadOnly { get; set; }
        public string SchSms { get; set; }
        public string AlertSms { get; set; }
        public object Temp { get; set; }
        public string GMTOffset { get; set; }
        public string SvrGMT { get; set; }
        public object ClientType { get; set; }
        public string EnableNews { get; set; }
        public string PublicSlideNews { get; set; }
        public string PrivateSlideNews { get; set; }
        public int DealerTreePriv { get; set; }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var jsonString =
      "{\"sessionid\":null,\"VersionInfo\":{\"Rel\":0,\"Ver\":0,\"Patch\":0,\"ForceUpdate\":0,\"UpdateType\":0,\"Globals\":{\"MultiSessionsAllowed\":true,\"CommCalcType\":1,\"PriceChangedTimer\":20,\"ValidLotsLocation\":2,\"CustumizeTradeMsg\":true,\"FirstWhiteLabeledOffice\":null,\"DealerTreePriv\":0,\"ClientConnectTimer\":200,\"ClientTimeoutTimer\":500,\"DefaultLots\":0.01,\"WebSecurityID\":\"agagag\",\"ServerGMT\":3}},\"SystemLockInfo\":{\"MinutesRemaining\":0,\"HoursRemaining\":0,\"DaysRemaining\":0,\"Maintanance\":0,\"WillBeLocked\":1},\"FirstWhiteLabel\":\"HS Dev\",\"WLID\":\"3\",\"CheckWhiteLabel\":true,\"Password\":\"1234\",\"Username\":\"obeidat\",\"SelectedAccount\":12345791,\"Name\":0,\"CompanyName\":\"HS Dev\",\"UserId\":-579,\"DemoClient\":\"0\",\"FName\":\"obeidat\",\"SName\":null,\"TName\":null,\"LName\":null,\"Sms\":null,\"isReadOnly\":\"0\",\"SchSms\":\"0\",\"AlertSms\":\"0\",\"Temp\":null,\"GMTOffset\":\"5\",\"SvrGMT\":\"3\",\"ClientType\":null,\"EnableNews\":\"0\",\"PublicSlideNews\":\"\",\"PrivateSlideNews\":\"Thanks for using our platform##We will inform you here with any private news\",\"DealerTreePriv\":1}";
        RootObject jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
        MessageBox.Show("hello " + jsonObject.Username + "" + jsonObject.UserId);

        int val1 = Convert.ToInt16(jsonObject.UserId);
        if (val1 > 0)

            MessageBox.Show("You are logedin");


        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Sorry Please login");
        }




    }




    //    // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
    //    ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.add.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
    //    appBarButton.Text = AppResources.AppBarButtonText;
    //    ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

    //    // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
    //    ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.AppBarMenuItemText);
    //    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuItem);
    //}



}
```

}

Please help me to parse all of the json result (locally i mean without conection to web)and what is the code to do that.

thank you all

Comment: What your web service is sending back appears to be invalid JSON. Looks to me like it's JSON wrapped inside a string. So you get a string value back and not any real JSON. For example, {"foo":"bar"} vs. "{\"foo\"}:\"bar\"}"

Comment: Welcome to SO by the way. Also, you don't need a connection to the web to parse JSON. And actually posting errors would sort of help too. It's likely why someone downvoted you. "I get an error" doesn't help anyone help you.

Comment: Hello Paul i have validate the result and its JSON and and when i put the full response to  var jsonString its give me 17 error try it and you will see the error

Comment: Hello all any one help me :(

Comment: Any one can help me :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your JSON is all a string property of "D". You can't deserialize it to RootClass. Second, your JSON contains invalid escape characters in the LastTickTime area. I removed both of these, and the JSON parses without errors of any kind. I just used a console app to test it.

```
     var s = "{\"sessionid\":null,\"VersionInfo\":{\"Rel\":0,\"Ver\":0,\"Patch\":0,\"ForceUpdate\":0,\"UpdateType\":0,\"Globals\":{\"MultiSessionsAllowed\":true,\"CommCalcType\":1,\"PriceChangedTimer\":20,\"ValidLotsLocation\":2,\"CustumizeTradeMsg\":true,\"FirstWhiteLabeledOffice\":null,\"DealerTreePriv\":0,\"ClientConnectTimer\":200,\"ClientTimeoutTimer\":500,\"DefaultLots\":0.01,\"WebSecurityID\":\"agagag\",\"ServerGMT\":3}},\"SystemLockInfo\":{\"MinutesRemaining\":0,\"HoursRemaining\":0,\"DaysRemaining\":0,\"Maintanance\":0,\"WillBeLocked\":1},\"FirstWhiteLabel\":\"HS Dev\",\"WLID\":\"3\",\"CheckWhiteLabel\":true,\"Password\":\"1234\",\"Username\":\"obeidat\",\"SelectedAccount\":12345791,\"Name\":0,\"CompanyName\":\"HS Dev\",\"UserId\":579,\"DemoClient\":\"0\",\"FName\":\"obeidat\",\"SName\":null,\"TName\":null,\"LName\":null,\"Sms\":null,\"isReadOnly\":\"0\",\"SchSms\":\"0\",\"AlertSms\":\"0\",\"Temp\":null,\"GMTOffset\":\"5\",\"SvrGMT\":\"3\",\"ClientType\":null,\"EnableNews\":\"0\",\"PublicSlideNews\":\"\",\"PrivateSlideNews\":\"Thanks for using our platform##We will inform you here with any private news\",\"DealerTreePriv\":1}";

     var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(s);
     Console.WriteLine(foo.UserId); // Writes 579
```

UPDATE

If you have no control over what you get back, do the following:
Take the response and get rid of the / combination. As such:

```
string webResponse = "your long web response from the server";
webResponse = webResponse.Replace(@"\/", "/");
// If dynamic isn't in the phone subset, you'll need a class here containing "d" as a string.
var jsonOuter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(webResponse);
var jsonInner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonOuter.d);

if (jsonInner.UserId > .....)
```

Comment: Thank you Paul, i have do the same and its working fine with me as i wrote before but this is a local test, the problem how to parse this if it`s came from Webservice i have no control on it? how i can parse the result of the http request to use it since i cant delete any thing from the response ? please help me if you have any idea to solve this problem..... thank you man :)

Comment: oh i dont know what i say  , i want to cry Paul its not working-- > this is the the link of the webservice i use (Its only working with httpwebrequest) http://5.153.2.2/hsdev/webservice.svc/login?username=%22user123%22&password=%221234567%22

Comment: It's not working because you posted the wrong code above! It's different between your post, and this link you just provided. Look at the data in your link. The second DealerTreePriv provided is NULL. This cannot convert so it throws an error. Why is it in there twice for the same object? It should only be in there one time, not twice.

Comment: Change DealerTreePriv from "int" to be "int?". Or get someone to fix your web service to return it as not nullable.

Comment: Dear Paul I have no control on the webservice , and i dont know how to solve this issue please advice.

Comment: As I said - change your class. Change DealerTreePriv to be "int?" and not "int".

Comment: Hello Paul i have made the change you want but its not working ? its work with you or not  ?????